# gsub not working for string with regex character (*)

Tags: r

test data:

```
new <- structure(list(date = structure(c(19289, 19290, 19291), tzone = "America/Bogota", class = "Date"), 
                      tracking_code = c("ppl-rmkt-aaa-aaa-aaa-20221024-pdp-preciopromo-none - Copia_tobuy", 
                                        "ppl-rmkt-aaa-aaa-aaa-20221024-pdp-preciopromo-none - Copia_tobuy", 
                                        "ppl-rmkt-aaa-aaa-aaa-20221024-pdp-preciopromo-none - Copia_tobuy"
                      ), visits = c(81L, 172L, 234L), orders = c(0L, 2L, 0L), units_purchase_event = c(0L, 
                                                                                                       2L, 0L), revenue_purchase_event = c(0, 8698, 0), revenue_dolars_sin_igv = c(0,
```

code:

```
new$tracking_code <- gsub(
  "ppl-rmkt-aaa-aa[*]a-aaa-20221024-pdp-preciopromo-none - Copia$",
  "ppl-lal-aaa-aa*a-aaa-20221024-pdp-preciopromo-none",
  new$tracking_code,
  ignore.case = TRUE
)
```

Instead of:

```
ppl-rmkt-aaa-aa*a-aaa-20221024-pdp-preciopromo-none - Copia_tobuy
```

I'm expecting:

```
ppl-lal-aaa-aa*a-aaa-20221024-pdp-preciopromo-none_tobuy
```

Comment: Your strings are so long it's hard to tell what's going on. Could you shorten them to make it easier to see the problem?

Comment: And why are you using `$` at the end of your regex pattern? In regex, `$` matches the end of a string. `"a$"` will match strings that end with `a`. Your regex pattern has ` Copia$`, so it will match strings that end in `Copia`. But your sample inputs end in `Copia_tobuy`, so none of them will match.

Comment: @GregorThomas just wanna replace that part, not: `_tobuy` . 

Edited question with shortened sentences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is with the `$` end marker in the gsub pattern argument:

Remove the `$` at the end, which is looking for the end of the source string.

So:

```
new$tracking_code <- gsub("ppl-rmkt-s22ultra128gbgreen-sm[*]s908ezglltp-cyberwow-20221024-pdp-preciopromo-none - Copia",
                              "ppl-lal-s22ultra128gbgreen-sm*s908ezglltp-cyberwow-20221024-pdp-preciopromo-none", new$tracking_code,
                              ignore.case = TRUE)
```

Comment: FYI, brackets are another way to match literals, OP's `[*]` is not a problem. See `gsub(pattern = "[*]", replacement = "Hi!", x = "ab*.%")` as an example.

Comment: Many thanks, @Gregor Thomas. I have updated my answer to remove this inaccurate point.